# What clearfixes support what browsers?

Tags: css, clearfix

So there are a billion clearfixes out there. Does anyone have a collection of them with their browser support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a summary of the most used.

Solution 1: The Old School Way

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Method 2: The Overflow Way

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden; /* can also be "auto" */
}
```

Method 3: The “clearfix” Class

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
  zoom: 1; /* ie 6/7 */
}
```

*And if you don’t need to support anything below IE8*

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Method 4: The Future contain-floats Value

```
.container {
  min-height: contain-floats;
}
```

Src: http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/